# ConvertFrom-Json is giving System.Object[] for some sections in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new to Windows PowerShell. I am trying to fire ConvertFrom-Json  command for the below Json :-

```
$ret=[{"ID":"ABC","type":"Test","code":"AD","enabled":true,"sourceMappings":[{"source":"Test","values":[{"code":"AD","value":"Anderson","enabled":true,"canonicalValue":true,"downStreamDefaultValue":true}]}],"startDate":0,"endDate":0,"updatedBy":"YY","updateDate":1590085877449,"version":4}]
```

and I am getting below output :-

```
ID             : ABC
type           : Test
code           : AD
enabled        : True
sourceMappings : {@{source=Test; values=System.Object[]}}
startDate      : 0
endDate        : 0
updatedBy      : YY
updateDate     : 1590085877449
version        : 4
```

If you notice the values been assigned to System.Object[].Please help me how to get the original values in the output.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

I think the converting is all fine.

You can access the values via:

```
$tmp = $ret | ConvertFrom-Json
$tmp.sourcemappings
$tmp.sourcemappings.values.code
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Lets first make your `json` file more readable:

```json
{
"ID":"ABC",
"type":"Test",
"code":"AD",
"enabled":true,
"sourceMappings":[{"source":"Test","values":[{"code":"AD","value":"Anderson","enabled":true,"canonicalValue":true,"downStreamDefaultValue":true}]}],
"startDate":0,
"endDate":0,
"updatedBy":"YY",
"updateDate":1590085877449,
"version":4
}
```

Second of all, your way of defining `json` variable is incorrect. In powershell, you need to define `json` variables is surrounding the `json` content with `@"` and `"@`. The correct way to set `$ret` equal to your `json` file would be like this:

```
$ret=@"
{
"ID":"ABC",
"type":"Test",
"code":"AD",
"enabled":true,
"sourceMappings":[{"source":"Test","values":[{"code":"AD","value":"Anderson","enabled":true,"canonicalValue":true,"downStreamDefaultValue":true}]}],
"startDate":0,
"endDate":0,
"updatedBy":"YY",
"updateDate":1590085877449,
"version":4
}
"@
```

Where $ret would be considered a `string` data type. You could then convert the `json` with:

```
$var = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $ret
```

Where you could now interact with it like normal. For example, `$var.ID` would output `ABC` and if you tried checking the object type again with `$var.gettype()` it would output:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Where the type would be a `PSCustomObject`

**Update:** It seems as if I misunderstood the question, my bad!

The reason it says

```
sourceMappings : {@{source=Test; values=System.Object[]}}
```

Is because powershell doesn't want to display the whole value since there are many components in the value. You can view the values in the `sourceMappings` class with `$var.sourceMappings` where the output would be:

```
source values
------ ------
Test   {@{code=AD; value=Anderson; enabled=True; canonicalValue=True; downStreamDefaultValue=True}}
```

and you can keep on viewing deeper if you add on like `$var.sourceMappings.code` etc. etc.